# VSCODE php Intelephense find references showing duplicates

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I am running the latest version of vscode 1.26.1 and have the package php Intelephense installed v0.8.8 on macOS.

When I try to find all references on a function it duplicates some files. After I looked into it closely I found that the only difference was a double // before the app folder.

```
~/Sites/test//app/Http/Controllers
~/Sites/test/app/Http/Controllers
```

[image]

[image: Second reference]

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this? I tested it on 2 different macbooks and both have the same issue.

Comment: Try running *Intelephense: Clear Cache and Reload* from command palette. Also, make sure you don't have two similar extensions running at the same time (e.g. *PHP Intelephense* and *PHP IntelliSense*).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried that and still I get the same result.